# get post types by taxonomies in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, group-by, custom-post-type, taxonomy

How to get all the post types(not the posts) grouped by taxonomies? 
Is there any standard wordpress functions?

I want something like this

```
taxonomy_1 -> post_type_11, post_type_12, post_type_13,  ....
taxonomy_2 -> post_type_21, post_type_22, ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a query to get the taxonomies and the attached post types as arrays

```
$query = "
SELECT taxonomy, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT `post_type` SEPARATOR ',') AS `post_types`
FROM wp_term_taxonomy 
JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.`term_taxonomy_id` =  wp_term_taxonomy.`term_taxonomy_id`
JOIN wp_posts ON wp_term_relationships.`object_id` = wp_posts.`ID` 
/* you can add other conditions here like - AND post_status = 'published' */
GROUP BY taxonomy
";
```

then I call this query

```
$global wpdb;
$post_types_by_taxonomies = $wpdb->get_results( $query, OBJECT_K );
```

now we can loop through the result array

```
foreach($post_types_by_taxonomies as $taxonomy => $post_types_as_string){
    $post_types = explode(',', $post_types_as_string->post_types);
    echo '<hr />';
    echo $taxonomy;
    echo '<br />';
    echo '<br />';
    foreach($post_types as $post_type){
        echo $post_type;
        echo '<br />';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please check this one i hope this will work for you.

<?php

// get taxonomies terms links

function custom_taxonomies_terms_links(){

  // get post by post id

  $post = get_post( $post->ID );



  // get post type by post

  $post_type = $post->post_type;



  // get post type taxonomies

  $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( $post_type, 'objects' );



  $out = array();

  foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy_slug => $taxonomy ){



    // get the terms related to post

    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy_slug );



    if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {

      $out[] = "<h2>" . $taxonomy->label . "</h2>\n<ul>";

      foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

        $out[] =

          '  <li><a href="'

        .    get_term_link( $term->slug, $taxonomy_slug ) .'">'

        .    $term->name

        . "</a></li>\n";

      }

      $out[] = "</ul>\n";

    }

  }



  return implode('', $out );

}

?>
```